# combining multiple materials into one material (Unity)

Tags: unity, textures, blender, batching

I am confused with how should I texture my character.

I am using blender for modelling. And while my model is too complex I dont want to use uv map techniuqe. I can get what I need with using seperate materials. Therefore I assign different materials to different meshes in Blender then import it to Unity. Therefore I have lots of different material in one model and I think it increases draw call. What can I do to combine these material into just one.

I thought baking would be sollution but while my character is dynamic I can not get a good result.

Comment: A picture of your character would go a long way here, so we know what kinds of material effects you're trying to combine.

Comment: I use standart shader at unity. I will upload picture when I can